# Is there any way to avoid reactjs SPA remount should the user manually edit the URL rather than route via react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Let's say I have a React app at `my.site.com` that uses react-router-dom. Inside my `<Home />` component I listen for router location updates via the usual hook.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const location = useLocation();
console.log(location.key);
```

The value of `location.key` for the first page is always `default`. Fine. I click on a react-router-dom `<Link />` to navigate to an `<SecondPage />` component at `my.site.com/secondpage`, which has the same code as listed above. This time the value of `location.key` is a random string like `zd7ju3rp`. My next move, instead of using another `<Link />` component, is to manually edit the address bar to `my.site.com/thirdpage` and hit ENTER.

From react-router-dom's perspective we have remounted the SPA, meaning the value of `location.key` will once again be `default`, therefore indistinguishable from the key two 'pages' previously. Not only that, but the chances of buggy behaviours - such as the following code not being called - increase.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.key)
}, [location]);
```

Is there any way to make react-router(-dom) recognise that the manual edit of the URL should not remount the SPA, but simply keep the already-mounted instance and navigate to the next URL?

Comment: *Are there* two separate apps running in your domain, or just the one? Are `"/"`, `"/secondpage"`, and `"/thirdpage"` just three pages in the same React app? If the user is manually updating the URL this is simply a fresh page load, e.g. the app mounts. Can you [edit] to clarify what issue this causes in your code?

Comment: Its a good point, it simply remounts. Have edited, thanks. Is there a way of avoiding a remount should the user manually edit the URL?

Comment: "Is there a way of avoiding a remount should the user manually edit the URL?" - No, it's a request to the server for the page at the URL. React-Router-DOM doesn't come into play until *after* the server has served the file for the requested URL and the page is loaded and e.g. the app mounted again so routing can be handled internally. If you have some sort of loading logic then it needs to account/handle this use case. You still haven't really explained what the issue or problem is that you are trying to solve for here.